# Resetting password expiry date by number of days instead of specifying date

Tags: linux, password, passwd

Is there a way with either commands passwd or chage to force the password to expire 90 days from the time of command execution?

I know I can do it by date, such as:

```
chage -E "2014-07-31" userid
```

But I'm looking for a way to do it by with a number instead of a specific date.

Thank you!

Comment: `chage -M 90 userid`

Comment: Doesn't that just change the the MAX number of days for that password to expire?

From the man entry: 
-M, --maxdays MAX_DAYS
Set the maximum number of days during which a password is valid.

I'm pretty sure it doesn't actually reset the last time the password was changed.

Comment: If it is a shell script, you can probably calculate 90 days from current date using `date` command and set the expiration using `-E` flag itself. If however, you need to specify the days, I see you have to change some files such as `\etc\login.defs` and `etc\default\useradd`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`chage` doesn't handle date differences by itself, but you can let the shell take care of that and give `chage` a number of days since 1970-01-01 instead of a YYYY-MM-DD date representation:

```
chage -E $(( $(date +%s)/3600/24 + 90 )) userid
```

<sub>(Replace 90 with any number of days.)</sub>

---

Changing the expiration date of the *password* rather than the *account* is a little trickier — in fact, you cannot set an actual expiration date for the password, just a maximum age (using `chage -M`).

To compute the maximum age required for the password to expire 90 days from now, we need to jump through a few more hoops:

```
userid=johndoe
pwd_age=$(grep "^$userid:" /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f 3)
now=$(( $(date +%s) / 3600 / 24 ))
age_at_expiry_date=$(( $now + 90 - $pwd_age ))
chage $userid -M $age_at_expiry_date
```

If you don't mind it being rather convoluted, you can even combine that into a one-liner:

```
userid=johndoe chage $userid -M $(( $(date +%s) / 3600 / 24 + 90 - $(grep "^$userid:" /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f 3) ))
```

---

If you don't mind overwriting the date when the password was last changed, you can just

```
chage -M 90 -d $(date +%F) userid
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it, but it didn't really have the desired effect. Maybe I'm not expressing what I want correctly.

Instead of updating the 'Password expires' field (see `code`chage -l userid`code`), it updated the 'Account expires' field. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE `-E` does indeed change the account expiration date, not the one of the password. I just assumed that's what you were trying to do since you used `-E` in your question. As for the password, you can't set an actual expiry date, just a maximum age (using `-M`, as Ramesh already pointed out).

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE I've updated my answer to include a solution for the *password* (rather than *account*) expiry.

Comment: Thanks, this is a step in the right direction. I'm going to have to twiddle around, because I still want the `"Maximum number of days between password change"` to be 90 days. From what I understand, the password expiry date is computed based on the 'Last password change' and the 'Max number of days between password change'.
So modifying the 'Last password change' to `now` somehow would resolve my issue altogether.
I looked at /etc/shadow and the third column corresponds to "Last password change (lastchanged): Days since Jan 1, 1970 that password was last changed". Just need to modify that (?)

Comment: Haha, I gave it a try and it had...unexpected consequences; it reset every field to never and -1. I guess Linux doesn't like me manipulating /etc/shadow directly.

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE Alright, I've added that option to my answer as well.

Comment: The option you added had the desired behavior: modifies the `Last password change` date to the current date, and sets the password expiry 90 days from now. Sorry for formulating my original question so poorly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

RHEL 6.8

```
#set passwd max no days = 30
passwd username -x30
```

Comment: That option seems to exist on Debian as well, so I suspect it's pretty universal on Linux (I have no idea if it does what OP asks for, though). Anyway, answers are much better with a little prose explaining them, not just a command to run. For example, you could change the comment to a sentence, and include a reference to the manpage.